# use subquery in inner join mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

This is my query

```
SELECT CONCAT(`SM_Title`,' ',`SM_Full_Name`) AS NAME,
`RG_Date`,
`RG_Reg_No`,
`RG_Stu_ID`,
`SM_Tell_Mobile`,
`SM_Tel_Residance`,
`RG_Reg_Type`,
Default_Batch,
`RG_Status`,
`RG_Final_Fee`,
`RG_Total_Paid`,
(`RG_Final_Fee`-`RG_Total_Paid`) AS TOTALDUE, 
SUM(`SI_Ins_Amount` - `SI_Paid_Amount`) AS AS_AT_APRIAL_END 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT `SI_Ins_Amount`,
 `SI_Reg_No` 
  FROM
  `student_installments` 
  GROUP BY MONTHNAME(`SI_Due_Date`)) Z ON
  Z.`SI_Reg_No` = `registrations`.`RG_Reg_No` 
FROM `registrations` 
LEFT JOIN `student_master` ON `student_master`.`SM_ID` = `registrations`.`RG_Stu_ID`
LEFT JOIN `student_installments` ON `student_installments`.`SI_Reg_No` = `registrations`.`RG_Reg_No` 
WHERE (`RG_Reg_Type` LIKE '%HND%' OR `RG_Reg_Type` LIKE '%LMU%' ) 
AND `SI_Due_Date` <= '2014-04-30' GROUP BY `SI_Reg_No`
```

It gave me an error near

`1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Z LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1`

Comment: I guess `FROM registrations` should go above first join after the select list.

Comment: In addition to the problem with the INNER JOIN coming before the FROM, your sub query seems dubious. You are gettng the SI_Reg_No and SI_Ins_Amount but grouping by SI_Due_Date. I assume that SI_Reg_No refers to the particular student, but with the group by it will group up for all students (which SI_Reg_No is brought back is undefined). Further your main query has a group by SI_Reg_No when you do not return this field (rather you return RG_Reg_No), and on the GROUP BY you do not define which tables value of SI_Reg_No you want to use (ie, z.SI_Reg_No or student_installments.SI_Reg_No).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(SM_Title,' ',SM_Full_Name) AS NAME,
RG_Date, 
RG_Reg_No,
RG_Stu_ID,
SM_Tell_Mobile,
SM_Tel_Residance,
RG_Reg_Type,
Default_Batch,
RG_Status,
RG_Final_Fee,
RG_Total_Paid,
(RG_Final_Fee-RG_Total_Paid) AS TOTALDUE,
 SUM(SI_Ins_Amount - SI_Paid_Amount) AS AS_AT_APRIAL_END
FROM registrations  
 INNER JOIN 
(SELECT SI_Ins_Amount,SI_Reg_No 
FROM student_installments 
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(SI_Due_Date)) Z ON Z.SI_Reg_No = registrations.RG_Reg_No 
LEFT JOIN student_master ON student_master.SM_ID = registrations.RG_Stu_ID 
LEFT JOIN student_installments ON student_installments.SI_Reg_No = registrations.RG_Reg_No 
WHERE (RG_Reg_Type LIKE '%HND%' OR RG_Reg_Type LIKE '%LMU%' ) 
AND SI_Due_Date <= '2014-04-30' 
GROUP BY SI_Reg_No
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice you have fogotten the left table or subselect that you want to join to the (SELECT SI_INs .....) and previous this I could see there is no from clause before join.

I hope this helps you
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You are using from clause in wrong position it should be just after selection of your columns, you can use below query:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(SM_Title,' ',SM_Full_Name) AS NAME ,RG_Date,RG_Reg_No,RG_Stu_ID,SM_Tell_Mobile,SM_Tel_Residance,RG_Reg_Type,Default_Batch,RG_Status,RG_Final_Fee,RG_Total_Paid,(RG_Final_Fee-RG_Total_Paid) AS TOTALDUE, SUM(SI_Ins_Amount - SI_Paid_Amount) AS AS_AT_APRIAL_END
FROM registrations AS reg
JOIN 
(SELECT 
SI_Ins_Amount,SI_Reg_No 
FROM student_installments
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(SI_Due_Date)) AS Z
ON Z.SI_Reg_No = reg.RG_Reg_No 
LEFT JOIN student_master AS sm 
ON sm.SM_ID = reg.RG_Stu_ID 
LEFT JOIN student_installments AS si 
ON si.SI_Reg_No = reg.RG_Reg_No 
WHERE (RG_Reg_Type LIKE '%HND%' OR RG_Reg_Type LIKE '%LMU%' ) AND SI_Due_Date <= '2014-04-30' 
GROUP BY SI_Reg_No;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the part below, from keyword should go before the inner join:

```
FROM registrations
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT SI_Ins_Amount,
    SI_Reg_No
  FROM student_installments
  GROUP BY MONTHNAME(SI_Due_Date)
 ) Z
ON Z.SI_Reg_No = registrations.RG_Reg_No
```